# Is it possible to build a jet engine that utilises all excess heat?

Tags: jet-engine

Is it possible to build a jet engine that utilises excess heat for thrust or does not produce any excess heat hence no need for cooling which is wasted energy

Comment: You cannae change the laws of physics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, any thermal machine always transfers energy from the heater to the cooler ([Carnot cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_heat_engine#Carnot's_theorem)). The maximal yield depends on the temperature difference and cannot achieve exactly 100%. It is equal

$$
1-\frac{T_\text{C}}{T_\text{H}}
$$

where Tc is the temperature of the surrounding air and Th is the temperature of the burning fuel. Jet engine as normally understood in aviation is a thermal machine.